# Can Tensorflow saturate a GPU with a batch size of 1?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running a modest 5 layer convolutional network in tensorflow here.

If I have a large enough batch size I can pretty much saturate the GPU. I've implemented asynchronous loading with the [tf.StagingArea](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/staging/StagingArea), and I print a warning message if it's ever starved because it's waiting on data loading. *I've confirmed that it is not waiting on the data loading at any point.*

As I reduce my batch size I notice that the GPU utilization drops. When I have a batch size of 1 I get 35% utilization on a 1080 TI GPU. At a batch size of 20 I get 50% utilization, and so on. It's also less notable on slower GPUs.

I've tested it with a loop over nothing but the main `sess.run` call to ensure I don't have any other code slowing things down.

I've reviewed the TF high-performance models [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models), but don't note any reference to small batch sizes.

I wonder if anyone has any insight on improving the performance, other than, "duh, just increase the batch size". I include batch size as a hyperparameter because it affects model regularization. I'd like to test with small batch sizes but still utilize the GPU fully if possible. Also, this is generally the case when a single train step takes sufficiently less than ~0.1 sec to process.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution now?

Comment: As far as I believe, the GPU will simply be inefficient if you don't do large matrix multiplications, and small batch sizes like this will simply tend to be inefficient to run on the GPU. I haven't put enough research into it to confidently answer the question myself yet.